# Writing and reading continuously in a file

Tags: python, python-3.x, io

I am currently trying to find a way to have a thread writing logs in a file, and another thread reading the log and processing them. I have found [a way](http://www.dabeaz.com/generators/) (part 5) to read continuously the data in a file, but I do have a problem with writing the file in the data.

When I try to write something in the file, I need to close it afterward, otherwise the file stay blank. But if I close the file, I can not read it anymore.
So my reading thread looks like this :

```
def follow(file):
    file.seek(0,0)
    while True:
        line = file.readline()
        if not line:
            time.sleep(0.1)
            continue
        yield line

file = open(self.path)
loglines = follow(self.file)
for line in loglines:
    print(line)
```

But to write, I used something like:

```
file = open(self.path, 'w')
file.write(self.generateLog())
file.close()
sleep(self.duration)
```

But, as soon as file.close() is called, I have an error in the reading part :

```
  line 38, in run
    for line in loglines:
  line 147, in follow
    line = file.readline()
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

But if I do not close the file after writing, it is never updated.
(I am just doing the writing part to be sure that the reading part is working. In theory, the log file would be updated by apache or something else).

EDIT : Thanks to the flush(), I do not have this problem anymore, thanks a lot !
But it seems that writing and reading can be hard. If I print the line that I write, and the one I read, I obtain something like :

```
Writing : 158.228.210.37 [...] "GET /cat/rzkpvwons HTTP/1.0" 505 1119
Reading : 5 1119
```

So the reading does not read the entire line. Any idea of the problem ?

EDIT2 : Just changing open(path,'w') to open(path,'a+') seems to be working in combinaison with the flush, should have thought about this earlier.
Thanks a lot !

Thank you very much,
Djaz

Comment: "When I try to write something in the file, I need to close it afterward, otherwise the file stay blank. " Maybe `.flush()` will help you with that. Don't know if it will solve all of your problems.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It does solve a part of the problem I guess. But then, I am facing a new one (see edit). 
Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Does this library do anything you need? https://github.com/B2W-BIT/and
Asynchronous input output logging library